# ASP MVC Multiple HTML begin form and multiple controller? Possible

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

Is there anyway to make multiple html begin forms call multiple controllers?

Example:

I have two forms A and B on 1 view, then form A call controller C and B calls D, is this possible to implement this? If so, would I use Ajax or any suggestion?

Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You dont need ajax for it.

Answer (score 3):

A form doesn't need to be tied to the controller which built its view. You can post to whatever you want:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "Home"))
{
    I'll post to the Home controller.
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeOtherAction", "Security"))
{
    I'll post to the Security controller.
}
```

This just renders regular forms, so:

```
<form action="/Home/SomeAction">
</form>

<form action="/Security/SomeOtherAction">
</form>
```

This is one of the many many things that ASP.NET MVC got right and WebForms did not. If you tried to post to a different aspx page in the WebForms world, it would not be so easy.